# Simple Output Prints Twice to JTextArea in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, output

I was wondering why the JTextArea prints the same line twice. Im using multithreading and im new to this concept. I was wondering if that's where the issue is. As of looking it over I tried seeing if any run methods were called twice to cause such a thing. There aren't any loops in the code either. The line that says "Prints twice?" in the GameThread class is where the issue starts. Thanks for help.

**Main Menu Class**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class MainMenu {

    private JFrame menu;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainMenu window = new MainMenu();
                    window.menu.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public MainMenu() throws IOException {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    private void initialize() throws IOException {
        menu = new JFrame();
        menu.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        menu.setTitle("Zombie Game");
        menu.setBounds(100, 100, 574, 374);
        menu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        menu.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JButton btnPlay = new JButton("Play");
        
        // button action on click
        btnPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    GameScreen enterGame = new GameScreen();
                    menu.setVisible(false);
                    enterGame.run();
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Zombie Survival");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 40));
        lblNewLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(118, 34, 381, 73);
        menu.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
        btnPlay.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnPlay.setForeground(Color.RED);
        btnPlay.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 17));
        btnPlay.setToolTipText("Click to begin.");
        btnPlay.setBounds(225, 190, 118, 54);
        menu.getContentPane().add(btnPlay);
    }
}
```

**Game Board**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class GameScreen {

    private JFrame gameFrm;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public void run() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GameScreen window = new GameScreen();
                    window.gameFrm.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public GameScreen() throws InterruptedException {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    private void initialize() throws InterruptedException {
        gameFrm = new JFrame();
        gameFrm.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        gameFrm.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 478, 718, 134);
        gameFrm.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        
        JTextArea displayTextArea = new JTextArea();
        displayTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
        displayTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        displayTextArea.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    
                }
            }
        });
        
        scrollPane.setViewportView(displayTextArea);
        displayTextArea.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        displayTextArea.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        displayTextArea.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        
        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new CustomOutputStream(displayTextArea));
        System.setOut(printStream);
        
        
        JLabel forestPicture = new JLabel("New label");
        forestPicture.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\fstal\\Documents\\Java Programs\\UpdatedZombieGame\\src\\gameForest.jpg"));
        forestPicture.setBounds(0, 0, 738, 622);
        gameFrm.getContentPane().add(forestPicture);
        gameFrm.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        gameFrm.setTitle("Zombie Game");
        gameFrm.setBounds(100, 100, 752, 659);
        gameFrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        
        // Game work
        GameThread gThread = new GameThread();
        gThread.start();
    }
}
```

**Thread Class**

```
public class GameThread extends Thread {
    
    static String [] zombies = {"Zombie", "Fast Zombie", "Big Zombie", "Crawler"};
    static String [] bag = {"Assault Rifle", "SMG", "Shotgun", "Sniper"};
    static int [] zHealth = {100, 90, 200, 50};
    static int [] damage = {90, 80, 100, 200};
    static int playerHealth = 50;
    
    public void run() {
        
        try {
            
            System.out.println("Zombies are coming!");
            //Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("Prints twice?");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomOutputStream Class for TextArea**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class CustomOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    private JTextArea displayTextArea;
    
    CustomOutputStream(JTextArea textArea) {
        this.displayTextArea = textArea;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        
        // redirects data to the text area
        displayTextArea.append(String.valueOf((char)b));
        // scrolls the text area to the end of data
        displayTextArea.setCaretPosition(displayTextArea.getDocument().getLength());
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: My immediate issue is you're modifying the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

Answer (score 2):

You're creating two instance of the `GameScreen`, so your output get's printed twice

When you perform...

```
btnPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            GameScreen enterGame = new GameScreen();
            menu.setVisible(false);
            enterGame.run();
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

It calls the `GameScreen` constructor, which calls `initialize()`

```
/**
 * Create the application.
 *
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
public GameScreen() throws InterruptedException {
    initialize();
}
```

And when you call `run`, it does it again...

```
/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public void run() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GameScreen window = new GameScreen();
                window.gameFrm.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You really don't need to do this again in `run`.

Now that we've discussed that problem, you have a number of other issues.

Firstly, Swing is NOT thread safe and you should never modify the UI (or anything the UI relies on) from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for some more details (and possible solutions)

Second, `null` layouts are generally a bad idea - it made a mess of your UI on my PC.  You should really take the time to learn how to use the various layout managers available in the API - see [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)